# How do I keep the current accordion open on postback using just styles?

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I am trying to figure out how to keep the current accordion pane open during a postback. I have looked through the posts but all of them are using the actual accordion feature in jQuery, whereas I am using just css.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Editor.aspx.vb" Inherits="Editor" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>MLE Editor</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="Styles/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // The Accordion Effect
        $('.eventHeader').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">        
        <div id="eventOptions">
            <div id="eventsContainer"> 
                <h2 class="eventHeader">Event 1</h2><div class="eventContent"><p>Event options</p></div>
                <h2 class="eventHeader">Event 2</h2><div class="eventContent"><p>Event options</p></div>
                <h2 class="eventHeader">Event 3</h2><div class="eventContent"><p>Event options</p></div>
                <h2 class="eventHeader">Event 4</h2><div class="eventContent"><p>Event options</p></div>
                <h2 class="eventHeader">Event 5</h2><div class="eventContent"><p>Event options</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnPostback" Runat="server" Text="Postback" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does you post back do?  If you are reloading the page then you need to add the class to which ever one was open previously otherwise you could use an update panel so that only the processed part of the page is reloaded

Comment: This is just a dumbed down version of the original file. Therefore my post back just writes out the current datetime on the screen.

Comment: I'd go with an update panel around where your date time is written to screen then

Comment: This helps me in my brief example above, but doesn't answer my actual question of how to do it using javascript. The version above is dumbed down and I tried to make it so that I wouldn't have to post the entire 2000 line aspx file.

Comment: What you need to do is either have a look at ajax postbacks or update panels to try to understand how they work.  If you do a postback it will reload your page which means anything clientside that has happened will be lost (ie any accordion clicks and jquery changes of class) or you could set a cookie (which I would advise against) when you click on the panels so it will tell you which panel is open and then when the page is reloaded you can use this cookie to reopen the correct panel

Answer (score 0):

Use Hidden filed to Store Index Id between postbacks

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnIndexValue1" Value="-1" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".eventContent").hide();
        var index = parseInt(document.getElementById("hdnIndexValue1").value);
        $('.eventContent:eq(' + index + ')').show();

        $('.eventHeader').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
            var index = $(".eventHeader").index(this);
            document.getElementById('hdnIndexValue1').value = index;
        });
    });
</script>
```